# How to set Focus and Modal way on a Winform/WPF Application hosted in VSTO Excel 2003 Add-in?

Tags: process, focus, vsto, modal-dialog

I have 2 questions :

**1)** In my VSTO Add-in, I created a button. When clicked, it starts a STA thread, launching a WPF Window (which is in fact my real application).
The application is treating Excel Data, sending them to Web services, etc etc.
At a particularly moment, I call :

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filePath);
```

the path is like "C:\file.xls". Indeed, it opens an Excel file.
The problem is that the focus is beeing made on this file instead of remaining the focus on my WPF window.
I tried to set the focus to the Current process, but since the new file opened and my WPF Window are hosted in the same Excel process, it didn't solve the problem at all...

Any idea ?

---

**2)** As you can see, as my WPF application is launched in a thread, even using a modal dialog, I can still modify the excel file in background... which is not what I want at all...
How to fix this, blocking the excel file in background ? Is it possible to do this using the Workbook COM object that I can control ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I solved my problem not using a thread.
I launch my application directly in the VSTA_Main thread (the Add-in thread), causing a freeze on my button...

Since it's not another thread, my entire process in blocking.

For the second question, I launched another Excel process like that :

```
            ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("Excel.exe",filePath);
            Process.Start(info);
```

I still have a little bug with the generation of the Excel file, but still solved my principal problem.